# Google Adwords API Sitelink Extension Reporting

Tags: api, google-ads-api

Is it possible through the Google Adwords v201809 API to get data on Sitelink extensions?

I haven't seen that as one of the available reports.

Thanks,
Jared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad extensions such as sitelinks are handled via the concept of [feeds](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/feed-services) in the Adwords API.

You'll have to use the [`PLACEHOLDER_FEED_ITEM_REPORT`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/placeholder-feed-item-report) to get statistics on feed items. To only get metrics for sitelinks, add the accoring predictate to your report definition.

Also take a look at the `IsSelfAction` dimension that help you distinguish between a click on the extension itself vs. a click on the ad.

As an example, this query returns a list of all sitelinks and the corresponding impressions and clicks:

```
SELECT CampaignName, PlaceholderType, AttributeValues, Impressions, Clicks
FROM PLACEHOLDER_FEED_ITEM_REPORT
WHERE IsSelfAction = True AND PlaceholderType = 1
```

Comment: This gave me the information I needed! I just had to parse out the JSON in the AttributeValues field.

Comment: That's great to hear. Would you mind accepting the answer then? :)